# Palindromic coin toss sequence

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

A fair coin is tossed 8 times then find the probability that resulting sequence of heads and tails looks the same when viewed from beginning or from the end?

How to approach this question because making cases would be such a difficult task?

Comment: The first $4$ throws uniquely determine the pattern, so the probability is $2^{-4}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, it is asking for the number of palindromic sequences. A palindromic sequence is one which is read forwards the same as it is backwards. So we can fix our first 4 coins in the sequence to be anything, and then just reverse and append the sequence to get a palindrome. So you would get $$\frac{2^4}{2^8}=\frac{1}{16}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let's just toss the coin $4$ times. Now we know what all the rest of the tosses must be, and the probability of getting the right ones is just $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4=\frac{1}{16}$$

Answer (score 3):

For each one of $2^4$ prefixes, there is a "mirror" postfix.

Hence the number of palindromes is $2^4=16$.

The total number of sequences is $2^8=256$.

Hence the probability of a palindrome is $\dfrac{16}{256}=\dfrac{1}{16}$.